# 入力された日付が正しいものかチェックするには？

Tags: python, python3

こちらで指定する4桁の日付の記載方法から、存在している日付かどうかをチェックをしたいです。

例えば8月23日だったら0823のような感じで、こちらは実際に存在している日付なのですが、9999のような実際にありえない日付だった場合、エラーを出すようにしたいです。
4桁と数字のチェックから、4桁の数字が存在する日付なのかをチェックするにはどのようにすればいいかご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
time=input("日付を入力をしてください：")
if len(time)==4 :
    if time.isdigit()==True:
        print("正常")
    else:
        print("数字ではありません")
else:
    print("桁数が違います")
```

Comment: チェックだけが目的のプログラムなのでしょうか？ チェックした後、その日付を使って処理するのではないでしょうか？ そうであれば、metropolisさんの回答のように実際に変換するのが現実的な気がします。

Answer (score 3):

"python date validation" で google 検索すると、例えば以下のページがヒットします。

[How do I validate a date string format in python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870663/2322778)

[回答の一つ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870690/2322778) を参考にすると、datetime モジュールを使った以下のような方法が紹介されています。

> ```py
> from datetime import datetime
>
> datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
> ```

もし不正な日付が指定された場合は `ValueError` が発生するので、`try` と `expect` を使って例外処理を書いてやればよさそうです。

今回の質問の例に当てはめるなら、日付のフォーマット指定の部分は以下の様になります。

```
datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m%d")
```

Comment: 閏年に関して: `strptime` のデフォルトは1900年なので、[2月29日がはじかれます](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#id8)。
もし、他の回答のように2月29日を受け入れる場合は、適当な閏年の年数を追加で指定しておくのがよいと思います。
例: `datetime.strptime("2000" + date_string, "%Y%m%d")`

Answer (score 1):

以下は Pandas モジュールの `to_datetime()` を使う方法です。

```py
import pandas as pd

def validate_date_string(date_str):
    return len(date_str) == 4 and \
           pd.to_datetime(f'2000{date_str}', format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce') is not pd.NaT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testing = ['0801', '0229', '9999', '', 'abcd']
    for t in testing:
        print(validate_date_string(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

変則的なコードですが、正規表現で妥当性チェックする方法もあります。
下記のコードでは、`is_date`関数に文字列を渡すと、4桁の月日文字列(うるう年の"0229"を含む)ならばTrueを返します。

```
import re

def is_date(s: str) -> bool:
    pattern = re.compile("(01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$|"  # 31日までの月 \
                         "(04|06|09|11)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)$|"              # 30日までの月 \
                         "(02(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]))$")                          # 29日までの月
    return pattern.match(s) != None

# 正常データ
assert is_date("0101")
assert is_date("0229")
assert is_date("0430")
assert is_date("1231")

# 異常データ
assert is_date("0000") == False
assert is_date("0132") == False
assert is_date("0230") == False
assert is_date("1301") == False
assert is_date("9999") == False
assert is_date("101") == False
assert is_date("01011") == False
assert is_date("OIOI") == False
```

**参考資料**

[yyyymmdd形式日付文字列の妥当性をチェックする正規表現を読み解く](https://qiita.com/shojit/items/c633a329dbbcc56923d6)